# Can't deserialize xml with element starting with 'μ'

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have an xml configuration file:

```
<Instruments>
  <Instrument Name="uEyeFF1" Assembly="Instruments" Class="IDSuEye1240SE">
    <Settings>
      <IDSuEye1240SESettings>
        <Serial>4102801225</Serial>
        <µmPerPixel>5.3</µmPerPixel>
        <Color>true</Color>
      </IDSuEye1240SESettings>
    </Settings>
  </Instrument>
  <!-- more Instruments -->
</Instruments>
```

and a class to which the `<IDSuEye1240SESettings>` node is deserialized:

```
[Serializable]
public class IDSuEye1240SESettings
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public double µmPerPixel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public bool Color { get; set; }
}
```

But when deserializing, I get the following error:

> 'There is an error in XML document (69, 10).' in Utilities.Load() as System.Void
>   
>    at *path hidden* 'Name cannot begin with the 'µ' character, hexadecimal value 0xB5. Line 69, position 10.' in System.Xml.Throw() as System.Void
>   
>    *rest of stack trace...*

On a different PC, an earlier compiled version of the same application is running, and I am seemingly able to deserialize the xml to the class. But the developer who wrote it is not around.

As far as I know, the working code doing the deserialization should be the same as the current code:

```
// the <Settings> node's children is value below
_settings = ConvertNode<IDSuEye1240SESettings>(((XmlNode[])value).First())

public T ConvertNode<T>(XmlNode node)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    sw.Write(node.OuterXml);
    sw.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T result = (T)ser.Deserialize(ms);
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible that there is something different in the compiled code which works to allow the 'µ' character to start an xml element name?

I had found a difference in the first line of the xml files between the PC's:

Working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Instruments
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com Instruments.xsd">
```

Not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Instruments 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com Instruments.xsd">
```

But I removed the encoding attribute but that only removed the red underline below the 'µ' for the new file open in the IDE. It didn't solve the serialization issue.

The schema files are identical for both PCs, if that matters.

Is it possible to allow the illegal character to start an xml node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decompiled *System.Xml* to find out why this exception might occur and I think I found an answer...

**In short**

There is no way to crack into it. But it is possible to solve your problem without changing XML.

**In long**

Unfotunetly *XML fifth edition* is considerably differs in deifinition of characters which can be used to start tag names. Here is decompiled constants from *System.Xml* which proves my words:

```
#if XML10_FIFTH_EDITION
        // StartNameChar without ':' -- see Section 2.3 production [4]
        const string s_NCStartName =
            "\u0041\u005a\u005f\u005f\u0061\u007a\u00c0\u00d6" +
            "\u00d8\u00f6\u00f8\u02ff\u0370\u037d\u037f\u1fff" +
            "\u200c\u200d\u2070\u218f\u2c00\u2fef\u3001\ud7ff" +
            "\uf900\ufdcf\ufdf0\ufffd";

        // NameChar without ':' -- see Section 2.3 production [4a] 
        const string s_NCName =
            "\u002d\u002e\u0030\u0039\u0041\u005a\u005f\u005f" +
            "\u0061\u007a\u00b7\u00b7\u00c0\u00d6\u00d8\u00f6" +
            "\u00f8\u037d\u037f\u1fff\u200c\u200d\u203f\u2040" +
            "\u2070\u218f\u2c00\u2fef\u3001\ud7ff\uf900\ufdcf" +
            "\ufdf0\ufffd";
#else
        const string s_NCStartName =
            "\u0041\u005a\u005f\u005f\u0061\u007a" +
            "\u00c0\u00d6\u00d8\u00f6\u00f8\u0131\u0134\u013e" +
            "\u0141\u0148\u014a\u017e\u0180\u01c3\u01cd\u01f0" +
            "\u01f4\u01f5\u01fa\u0217\u0250\u02a8\u02bb\u02c1" +
            "\u0386\u0386\u0388\u038a\u038c\u038c\u038e\u03a1" +
            "\u03a3\u03ce\u03d0\u03d6\u03da\u03da\u03dc\u03dc" +
            "\u03de\u03de\u03e0\u03e0\u03e2\u03f3\u0401\u040c" +
            "\u040e\u044f\u0451\u045c\u045e\u0481\u0490\u04c4" +
            "\u04c7\u04c8\u04cb\u04cc\u04d0\u04eb\u04ee\u04f5" +
            "\u04f8\u04f9\u0531\u0556\u0559\u0559\u0561\u0586" +
            "\u05d0\u05ea\u05f0\u05f2\u0621\u063a\u0641\u064a" +
            "\u0671\u06b7\u06ba\u06be\u06c0\u06ce\u06d0\u06d3" +
            "\u06d5\u06d5\u06e5\u06e6\u0905\u0939\u093d\u093d" +
            "\u0958\u0961\u0985\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993\u09a8" +
            "\u09aa\u09b0\u09b2\u09b2\u09b6\u09b9\u09dc\u09dd" +
            "\u09df\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10" +
            "\u0a13\u0a28\u0a2a\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36" +
            "\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a5e\u0a72\u0a74" +
            "\u0a85\u0a8b\u0a8d\u0a8d\u0a8f\u0a91\u0a93\u0aa8" +
            "\u0aaa\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5\u0ab9\u0abd\u0abd" +
            "\u0ae0\u0ae0\u0b05\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13\u0b28" +
            "\u0b2a\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b36\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b3d" +
            "\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f\u0b61\u0b85\u0b8a\u0b8e\u0b90" +
            "\u0b92\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f" +
            "\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8\u0baa\u0bae\u0bb5\u0bb7\u0bb9" +
            "\u0c05\u0c0c\u0c0e\u0c10\u0c12\u0c28\u0c2a\u0c33" +
            "\u0c35\u0c39\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85\u0c8c\u0c8e\u0c90" +
            "\u0c92\u0ca8\u0caa\u0cb3\u0cb5\u0cb9\u0cde\u0cde" +
            "\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0d05\u0d0c\u0d0e\u0d10\u0d12\u0d28" +
            "\u0d2a\u0d39\u0d60\u0d61\u0e01\u0e2e\u0e30\u0e30" +
            "\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40\u0e45\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e84" +
            "\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e8d\u0e94\u0e97" +
            "\u0e99\u0e9f\u0ea1\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0ea7" +
            "\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead\u0eae\u0eb0\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3" +
            "\u0ebd\u0ebd\u0ec0\u0ec4\u0f40\u0f47\u0f49\u0f69" +
            "\u10a0\u10c5\u10d0\u10f6\u1100\u1100\u1102\u1103" +
            "\u1105\u1107\u1109\u1109\u110b\u110c\u110e\u1112" +
            "\u113c\u113c\u113e\u113e\u1140\u1140\u114c\u114c" +
            "\u114e\u114e\u1150\u1150\u1154\u1155\u1159\u1159" +
            "\u115f\u1161\u1163\u1163\u1165\u1165\u1167\u1167" +
            "\u1169\u1169\u116d\u116e\u1172\u1173\u1175\u1175" +
            "\u119e\u119e\u11a8\u11a8\u11ab\u11ab\u11ae\u11af" +
            "\u11b7\u11b8\u11ba\u11ba\u11bc\u11c2\u11eb\u11eb" +
            "\u11f0\u11f0\u11f9\u11f9\u1e00\u1e9b\u1ea0\u1ef9" +
            "\u1f00\u1f15\u1f18\u1f1d\u1f20\u1f45\u1f48\u1f4d" +
            "\u1f50\u1f57\u1f59\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5d" +
            "\u1f5f\u1f7d\u1f80\u1fb4\u1fb6\u1fbc\u1fbe\u1fbe" +
            "\u1fc2\u1fc4\u1fc6\u1fcc\u1fd0\u1fd3\u1fd6\u1fdb" +
            "\u1fe0\u1fec\u1ff2\u1ff4\u1ff6\u1ffc\u2126\u2126" +
            "\u212a\u212b\u212e\u212e\u2180\u2182\u3007\u3007" +
            "\u3021\u3029\u3041\u3094\u30a1\u30fa\u3105\u312c" +
            "\u4e00\u9fa5\uac00\ud7a3";

        const string s_NCName =
            "\u002d\u002e\u0030\u0039\u0041\u005a\u005f\u005f" +
            "\u0061\u007a\u00b7\u00b7\u00c0\u00d6\u00d8\u00f6" +
            "\u00f8\u0131\u0134\u013e\u0141\u0148\u014a\u017e" +
            "\u0180\u01c3\u01cd\u01f0\u01f4\u01f5\u01fa\u0217" +
            "\u0250\u02a8\u02bb\u02c1\u02d0\u02d1\u0300\u0345" +
            "\u0360\u0361\u0386\u038a\u038c\u038c\u038e\u03a1" +
            "\u03a3\u03ce\u03d0\u03d6\u03da\u03da\u03dc\u03dc" +
            "\u03de\u03de\u03e0\u03e0\u03e2\u03f3\u0401\u040c" +
            "\u040e\u044f\u0451\u045c\u045e\u0481\u0483\u0486" +   
            "\u0490\u04c4\u04c7\u04c8\u04cb\u04cc\u04d0\u04eb" +  
            "\u04ee\u04f5\u04f8\u04f9\u0531\u0556\u0559\u0559" +
            "\u0561\u0586\u0591\u05a1\u05a3\u05b9\u05bb\u05bd" +
            "\u05bf\u05bf\u05c1\u05c2\u05c4\u05c4\u05d0\u05ea" +
            "\u05f0\u05f2\u0621\u063a\u0640\u0652\u0660\u0669" +
            "\u0670\u06b7\u06ba\u06be\u06c0\u06ce\u06d0\u06d3" +
            "\u06d5\u06e8\u06ea\u06ed\u06f0\u06f9\u0901\u0903" +
            "\u0905\u0939\u093c\u094d\u0951\u0954\u0958\u0963" +
            "\u0966\u096f\u0981\u0983\u0985\u098c\u098f\u0990" +
            "\u0993\u09a8\u09aa\u09b0\u09b2\u09b2\u09b6\u09b9" +
            "\u09bc\u09bc\u09be\u09c4\u09c7\u09c8\u09cb\u09cd" +
            "\u09d7\u09d7\u09dc\u09dd\u09df\u09e3\u09e6\u09f1" +
            "\u0a02\u0a02\u0a05\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13\u0a28" +
            "\u0a2a\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39" +
            "\u0a3c\u0a3c\u0a3e\u0a42\u0a47\u0a48\u0a4b\u0a4d" +
            "\u0a59\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a5e\u0a66\u0a74\u0a81\u0a83" +
            "\u0a85\u0a8b\u0a8d\u0a8d\u0a8f\u0a91\u0a93\u0aa8" +
            "\u0aaa\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5\u0ab9\u0abc\u0ac5" +
            "\u0ac7\u0ac9\u0acb\u0acd\u0ae0\u0ae0\u0ae6\u0aef" +
            "\u0b01\u0b03\u0b05\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13\u0b28" +
            "\u0b2a\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b36\u0b39\u0b3c\u0b43" +
            "\u0b47\u0b48\u0b4b\u0b4d\u0b56\u0b57\u0b5c\u0b5d" +
            "\u0b5f\u0b61\u0b66\u0b6f\u0b82\u0b83\u0b85\u0b8a" +
            "\u0b8e\u0b90\u0b92\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9c" +
            "\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8\u0baa\u0bae\u0bb5" +
            "\u0bb7\u0bb9\u0bbe\u0bc2\u0bc6\u0bc8\u0bca\u0bcd" +
            "\u0bd7\u0bd7\u0be7\u0bef\u0c01\u0c03\u0c05\u0c0c" +
            "\u0c0e\u0c10\u0c12\u0c28\u0c2a\u0c33\u0c35\u0c39" +
            "\u0c3e\u0c44\u0c46\u0c48\u0c4a\u0c4d\u0c55\u0c56" +
            "\u0c60\u0c61\u0c66\u0c6f\u0c82\u0c83\u0c85\u0c8c" +
            "\u0c8e\u0c90\u0c92\u0ca8\u0caa\u0cb3\u0cb5\u0cb9" +
            "\u0cbe\u0cc4\u0cc6\u0cc8\u0cca\u0ccd\u0cd5\u0cd6" +
            "\u0cde\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0ce6\u0cef\u0d02\u0d03" +
            "\u0d05\u0d0c\u0d0e\u0d10\u0d12\u0d28\u0d2a\u0d39" +
            "\u0d3e\u0d43\u0d46\u0d48\u0d4a\u0d4d\u0d57\u0d57" +
            "\u0d60\u0d61\u0d66\u0d6f\u0e01\u0e2e\u0e30\u0e3a" +
            "\u0e40\u0e4e\u0e50\u0e59\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e84" +
            "\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e8d\u0e94\u0e97" +
            "\u0e99\u0e9f\u0ea1\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0ea7" +
            "\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead\u0eae\u0eb0\u0eb9\u0ebb\u0ebd" +
            "\u0ec0\u0ec4\u0ec6\u0ec6\u0ec8\u0ecd\u0ed0\u0ed9" +
            "\u0f18\u0f19\u0f20\u0f29\u0f35\u0f35\u0f37\u0f37" +
            "\u0f39\u0f39\u0f3e\u0f47\u0f49\u0f69\u0f71\u0f84" +
            "\u0f86\u0f8b\u0f90\u0f95\u0f97\u0f97\u0f99\u0fad" +
            "\u0fb1\u0fb7\u0fb9\u0fb9\u10a0\u10c5\u10d0\u10f6" +
            "\u1100\u1100\u1102\u1103\u1105\u1107\u1109\u1109" +
            "\u110b\u110c\u110e\u1112\u113c\u113c\u113e\u113e" +
            "\u1140\u1140\u114c\u114c\u114e\u114e\u1150\u1150" +
            "\u1154\u1155\u1159\u1159\u115f\u1161\u1163\u1163" +
            "\u1165\u1165\u1167\u1167\u1169\u1169\u116d\u116e" +
            "\u1172\u1173\u1175\u1175\u119e\u119e\u11a8\u11a8" +
            "\u11ab\u11ab\u11ae\u11af\u11b7\u11b8\u11ba\u11ba" +
            "\u11bc\u11c2\u11eb\u11eb\u11f0\u11f0\u11f9\u11f9" +
            "\u1e00\u1e9b\u1ea0\u1ef9\u1f00\u1f15\u1f18\u1f1d" +
            "\u1f20\u1f45\u1f48\u1f4d\u1f50\u1f57\u1f59\u1f59" +
            "\u1f5b\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5d\u1f5f\u1f7d\u1f80\u1fb4" +
            "\u1fb6\u1fbc\u1fbe\u1fbe\u1fc2\u1fc4\u1fc6\u1fcc" +
            "\u1fd0\u1fd3\u1fd6\u1fdb\u1fe0\u1fec\u1ff2\u1ff4" +
            "\u1ff6\u1ffc\u20d0\u20dc\u20e1\u20e1\u2126\u2126" +
            "\u212a\u212b\u212e\u212e\u2180\u2182\u3005\u3005" +
            "\u3007\u3007\u3021\u302f\u3031\u3035\u3041\u3094" +
            "\u3099\u309a\u309d\u309e\u30a1\u30fa\u30fc\u30fe" +
            "\u3105\u312c\u4e00\u9fa5\uac00\ud7a3";
#endif
```

As to why your problem occurs: *s_NCStartName* constant defines which characters can be used to start your name, and in fifth edition it is VERY short (you will not find *0xB5* part in new edition string), and there is no way around it. It is constant, hardcoded into System.Xml. Well, it is Microsoft, they don't care about backward compatability.

**As to solution**

You have four options:

1. Attach old *System.Xml*, which is in my opinion is worse solution, but easiest.
2. Preprosses your xml: clean it from invalid start name characters.
3. Blame Microsoft on task tracker about this: lose of backward compatability.
4. Use other serialization frameworks, for example *Xml.Net*

**PS**

Small advise. You can rewrite ConvertNode like this:

```
    public static T ConvertNode<T>(XmlNode node)
    {
        using (var reader = new XmlNodeReader(node))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T) ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am going with option 2. It's still a mystery why the other machine works. Thanks for the improved ConvertNode :)

Comment: As I said, it just have older version of System.Xml with old constant definition, this is why it works.

Comment: The build is only 1-2 years old. When did this switch happen? Is there a difference between .Net frameworks?

Comment: Well, if you don't compare manually - I can't tell. But yes, it is possible for microsoft to change it in 2015-2016